# Commerce Kickstart 2 Display color as visual colour

Tags: commerce

In the 'Tops' Content type/Product Variation, the color selection in the 'catalog' shows up as multiple color blocks below the 'From $00.00' price information.

I've made up a new Content type and Product Variation, also with color. How do I get *all* the available product variation colors to show up as blocks of color below the price instead of just a single link to the first variations colour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You go into the Content Type and in the "Manage Display" -> "Product List" mode, you add a Field Extractor to get the color field and use view mode of 'Add to cart form' for view mode

Answer (score 0):

Go to Store setting -> Product settings -> Variation types -> your content type -> manage fields -> edit color(term reference)
enable the settings under "ATTRIBUTE FIELD SETTINGS"

[image]

Comment: The "Rendered term" option isn't available on mine. I installed CK2 without the sample store and data. I had to add the color taxonomy. In my new Product Variation field of color, how do I get this option to show?

Comment: I figured it out. No, your method is actually not the way to do this. You go into the Content Type and in the "Manage Display" -> "Product List" mode, you add a Field Extractor to get the color field and use view mode of 'Add to cart form' for view mode

Answer (score 0):

**Navigate:** Content > Content types

**Click Link:** (your type) > Manage display

**Select Button:** Manage display > Product list

*If it's not there, be sure to add it to the visible area:*

Product variations

Select: < Hidden >

Select: Field Extractor

**Click Button:** Settings

*Enter the following:*

Field: field_color

Formatter: Rendered entity

View mode: Add to Cart form - Attribute

**Click Button:** Update

**Click Button:** Save